# Compiler Error: "Statement invalid inside Type block"

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to update a very old VB6 program for my company. All of my changes were very trivial, all I did was change the values of a couple variables.  When I tried to compile the program I got the following error,

> Compile error: Statement invalid inside Type block.

The offending line of code is the first `Public` statement inside the type block, see the code snippet below.

```
Public Type Regphase
--->Public RESIST_CORE_INSUL_TEST As Double         'Mega OHM
    Public R_COLD_SERIES_16R As Double              'Type AB Regulators
    Public R_COLD_SERIES_15R As Double              'Type AB Regulators
    Public R_COLD_SERIES_15L As Double              'Type AB Regulators
    Public R_COLD_SERIES_16L As Double              'Type AB Regulators
```

I have a feeling this is just one of those random VB6 bugs but I have no idea how to get past it. I also tried using `Dim` instead of `Public` but got the same result.

I cannot post the full code because it may be considered proprietary - but please note there is an `End Type` statement after all the variables.

Comment: You cannot use accessibility modifiers inside a VB6 `Type`. The only allowed accessibility modifier [goes in front of the `Type` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/type-statement) and applies to the entire type.

Comment: I see someone has voted to close this question. I can't understand why, it's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 5):

The accessibility modifier only goes on the Type as a whole, not on each of the fields within it.

From the Visual Basic 6 Concepts Guide, "[Creating Your Own Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa262341%28v%3Dvs.60%29)", look at its example:

> ```
> Private Type SystemInfo
>    CPU As Variant
>    Memory As Long
>    VideoColors As Integer
>    Cost As Currency
>    PurchaseDate As Variant
> End Type
> ```

You can also refer to the Language Reference for the "[Type Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa266315%28v%3Dvs.60%29)".

Comment: I tried that but I started getting errors saying that a variable in the type could not be found when calling it from another module.  Also this program has been compiled many times as is.

Comment: @ezMoneys Then perhaps you could put together an MCVE of the issue you have when declaring the accessibility modifier correctly on only the Type and ask a separate question? Because your code here as you posted isn't valid, which is why it doesn't compile.

Comment: I actually just found a difrent version of the source code with the type declaration as is and it compiled just fine.  I’ll post the second error in a new question.